# Unable to call Azure Management Events REST API

Tags: api, rest, azure, curl

I am trying to use the rest api found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931934.aspx to get the azure events from my subscription. I have followed the instructions very carefully, but my GET requests return a 400 error:

```
{"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"The $filter query parameter value is invalid."}
```

My cURL request can be seen below. I've redacted any private info

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: bearer XXX" -H "content-type: application/json" "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/YYY/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2014-04-01&$filter=eventTimestamp%20ge%20%272016-07-25T22:00:37Z%27%20and%20eventTimestamp%20le%20%272016-07-25T23:36:37Z%27%20and%20eventChannels%20eq%20%27Admin,%20Operation%27"
```

I have tried many variations of the filter param, but I think this should be correct. Each space was replaced with a %20, and each ' was replaced with a %27.

If anyone can please inform me as to what the correct query should look like i'd really appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change the double quotes over the `url` to the single quotes. And it works fine on my side after modification.

E.G.,

```
curl -X GET -H 'Authorization: bearer <token>' -H 'content-type: application/json' 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/XXX/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2014-04-01&$filter=eventTimestamp%20ge%20%272016-07-25T22:00:37Z%27%20and%20eventTimestamp%20le%20%272016-07-25T23:36:37Z%27%20and%20eventChannels%20eq%20%27Admin,%20Operation%27'
```